# Save textbox value into JSON using angularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How to save a textbox value into a JSON file using AngularJS?
For example

```
<tr>
  <th>Email (ID)</th>
  <td><input type="text" size="15" id="email_id" ng-model="email_ID" /></td>
  <th>Contact Number</th>
  <td><input type="text" size="15" id="C_Num" ng-model="Contact" /></td>
```

On the click of button, the data residing on textbox should save on JSON file using AngularJS.

Comment: Can you provide your code snippet or JS fiddle?

Comment: Below is the code on which I am working:
<tr>
<th>Email (v-ID)</th>
<td><input type="text" size="15" id="email_id" ng-model="email_ID" /></td>
<th>Contact Number</th>
<td><input type="text" size="15" id="C_Num" ng-model="Contact" /></td>

Comment: @VIVEKJAIN: put this code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to transform something in JSON string you should have an object. It works with simple variables to but I would not make much difference for what you're trying to accomplish.

Anyway to save your model as a JSON string inside a `textarea` by clicking a button you should do something like this:

```
My name: <input type="text" ng-model="myModel.name">
My phone: <input type="text" ng-model="myModel.phone"> 
<button ng-click="jsonString = angular.toJson(myModel)">Save JSON</button>
<textarea ng-model="jsonString"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi @Synapse

Can you please give a complete flow of the above mentioned code? I am kind of noob in this area.

Comment: What if i want to save it this JSON as a file which work for me as data base instead of this textarea.. What should i do in this case please hel me in this senario.

Comment: Hi @Synapse,

As you give in above solution that you are downloading a JSON create a anchor tag but I want to save whole data of in existing JSON file. what should I do in that case ? Please help me.